# Why is adding a comment in an unrelated file affecting the theme of the app in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, themes, tailwind-css

I'm trying to implement a Next.js application with light and dark themes. I'm using TailwindCSS along with `next-themes`. My system preference theme is dark mode by default. However, when I load the page, I get the light themed background. The inspector shows that dark mode is enabled in the `html` attribute.

When I add a particular **comment** in an unrelated and un-imported file, the theme changes to the correct one.

Here's a [minimal example repository](https://github.com/captnTardigrade/MRE) that describes the issue. Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Clone the repository using

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/captnTardigrade/MRE.git
   ```
2. Install the dependencies using a shell by running the following in the folder

   ```bash
   npm install
   ```
3. Open a terminal and run `npm run dev`
4. Observe that the default background color loaded is light in color.
5. Add the following comment in `app/components/foo.tsx`:

   ```js
    // setTheme("dark");
   ```
6. Observe the background color. It should be dark.

> ***NOTE:***  Ensure that your default system preference is dark mode before trying to replicate the above steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building the project we get the following warning.

```bash
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files.
```

In your `globals.css` file you have put the `.dark` class inside an `@layer base` but as `dark` is not found in any source files it is not included in the final output.

When you add the comment in `app/components/foo.tsx` Tailwind detects the `dark` class.

This is explained in the documentation.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

> The way Tailwind scans your source code for classes is intentionally very simple — we don’t actually parse or execute any of your code in the language it’s written in, we just use regular expressions to extract every string that could possibly be a class name.